# Play framework onHandlerNotFound method

Tags: scala, global, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play framework 2.1.1 and as I tried to add a Global object to handle certain cases like BadRequest, HandlerNotFound and so on, I'm facing a strange error:

Here is how my Global.scala looks like:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }

  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result = {
    NotFound(
      views.html.common.notFoundPage(request.path)
    )
  }
}
```

Here is what I see when I start my application:

```
overriding method onHandlerNotFound in trait GlobalSettings of type (request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]; method onHandlerNotFound has incompatible type
```

It actually fails on compilation and spits out the error above. What is the reason behind this? I'm confused ad my IntelliJ does not show any errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using Play Framework 2.1 when building your project?

The [2.1 branch](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/GlobalSettings.scala#L124) indeed defines in `GlobalSettings`:

```
def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result
```

While the [2.2 branch](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/GlobalSettings.scala#L152) reads:

```
def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult]
```

Maybe you have different versions configured in IntelliJ and your build scripts?

For the 2.2 version you could write:

```
override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  Future.successful(NotFound(
    views.html.common.notFoundPage(request.path)
  ))
}
```